# Query (or algorithm?) to find cheapest overlapping flights from two distinct locations to one shared location

Tags: sql, algorithm, google-bigquery

Say we have a dataset of 500 000 flights from Los Angeles to 80 cities in Europe and back and from Saint Petersburg to same 80 cities in Europe and back. We want to find such 4 flights:

- from LA to city X, from city X back to LA, from St P to city X and from city X back to St P
- all 4 flights have to be in a time window of 4 days
- we are looking for the cheapest combined price of 4 flights
- city X can be any of 80 cities, we want to find such cheapest combination for all of them and get the list of these 80 combinations

The data is stored in BigQuery and I've created an SQL query, but it has 3 joins and I assume that under the hood it can have complexity of `O(n^4)`, because the query didn't finish in 30 minutes and I had to abort it.

Here's the schema for the table:

[image]

See the query below:

```
select * from (
  select in_led.`from` as city, 
    in_led.price + out_led.price + in_lax.price + out_lax.price as total_price,
    out_led.carrier as out_led_carrier, 
    out_led.departure as out_led_departure, 
    in_led.departure as in_led_date, 
    in_led.carrier as in_led_carrier, 
    out_lax.carrier as out_lax_carrier, 
    out_lax.departure as out_lax_departure, 
    in_lax.departure as in_lax_date, 
    in_lax.carrier as in_lax_carrier, 
    row_number() over(partition by in_led.`from` order by in_led.price + out_led.price + in_lax.price + out_lax.price) as rn
  from skyscanner.quotes as in_led
  join skyscanner.quotes as out_led on out_led.`to` = in_led.`from`
  join skyscanner.quotes as out_lax on out_lax.`to` = in_led.`from`
  join skyscanner.quotes as in_lax on in_lax.`from` = in_led.`from`
  where in_led.`to` = "LED"
    and out_led.`from` = "LED"
    and in_lax.`to` in ("LAX", "LAXA")
    and out_lax.`from` in ("LAX", "LAXA")
    and DATE_DIFF(DATE(in_led.departure), DATE(out_led.departure), DAY) < 4
    and DATE_DIFF(DATE(in_led.departure), DATE(out_led.departure), DAY) > 0
    and DATE_DIFF(DATE(in_lax.departure), DATE(out_lax.departure), DAY) < 4
    and DATE_DIFF(DATE(in_lax.departure), DATE(out_lax.departure), DAY) > 0
  order by total_price
) 
where rn=1
```

**Additional details:**

- all flights' departure dates fall in a 120 days window

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to optimize this query for better performance?
2. How to properly classify this problem? The brute force solution is way too slow, but I'm failing to see what type of problem this is. Certainly doesn't look like something for graphs, kinda feels like sorting the table a couple of times by different fields with a stable sort might help, but still seems sub-optimal.

Comment: Maybe doing a sliding window of 4 days, finding such combination for each window and then finding the cheapest one out of them is the way to go?.. Just some ideas

Comment: Might be better to organize your query by generating and selecting the 120 dates and then selecting the flights in the window (date, date+4) rather than what you have now. That will also allow for an efficient query on the flights (using a date index) instead of having to DATEDIFF every combination.

Comment: i would expected that one of requirements would be to have some min overlap in staying in city X. the second condition defines some time window but missing such overlap - so if this is a meet between passengers from LAX and LED - this condition is a must. please confirm. Also - are you using public data, so we can play with your problem?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant the overlap is this 4 day window, which is mentioned as item #2 in the first list. This is public data, I got it from a pretty slow SkyScanner API (took about 3 days of execution to gather), but it is stored in my personal BigQuery. I can share the CSV though, it's just 16 MB, however, the problem is a pretty generic one, so it doesn't have to be this specific data.

Comment: ok. it was not clear enough (at least for me) :o) another condition I would expected to see is a limit for max days in city X, meaning days between arrival and departure. Also, even though it is "pretty generic one" - it still will help if you can share data to play with - unless you want to get "pretty generic" answers/comments

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I am looking for any combinations where outbound flight and inbound flight are separated by maximum of 4 days and the dates overlap for flights from LA and St P for at least 1 day. Generic solution is exactly what I'm looking for -- an approach to problems like this. In particular, how to classify this problem in terms of what would be the tool to solving it (i.e. sorting, sliding window, dynamic programming, graphs or whatever). You can download a csv here https://storage.googleapis.com/exported-flights/flights.csv

Comment: Ok. So passengers overlap is actually at least 1 day! That is what was missing I think. Will play with this in a morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> The brute force solution is way too slow, but I'm failing to see what type of problem this is.
> so I would like to see solutions other than brute force if anyone here has ideas

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT *, UNIX_DATE(DATE(departure)) AS dep FROM `skyscanner.quotes`
), round_trips AS (
  SELECT t1.from, t1.to, t2.to AS back, t1.price, t1.departure, t1.dep first_day, t1.carrier, t2.departure AS departure2, t2.dep AS last_day, t2.price AS price2, t2.carrier AS carrier2, 
  FROM temp t1
  JOIN temp t2
  ON t1.to = t2.from
  AND t1.from = t2.to
  AND t2.dep BETWEEN t1.dep + 1 AND t1.dep + 3
  WHERE t1.from IN ('LAX', 'LED')
)
SELECT cityX, total_price,
  ( SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(t1.first_day, t1.last_day)) day
    JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(t2.first_day, t2.last_day)) day
    USING(day)
  ) overlap_days_in_cityX, 
  (SELECT AS STRUCT departure, price, carrier, departure2, price2, carrier2 
    FROM UNNEST([t1])) AS LAX_CityX_LAX, 
  (SELECT AS STRUCT departure, price, carrier, departure2, price2, carrier2 
    FROM UNNEST([t2])) AS LED_CityX_LED
FROM (
  SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY total_price LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.to cityX, t1.price + t1.price2 + t2.price + t2.price2 AS total_price, t1, t2 
    FROM round_trips t1
    JOIN round_trips t2
    ON t1.to = t2.to
    AND t1.from < t2.from
    AND t1.departure2 > t2.departure
    AND t1.departure < t2.departure2
  ) t
  GROUP BY cityX
)
ORDER BY overlap_days_in_cityX DESC, total_price
```

with output (just top 10 out of total 60 rows)

[image]

Brief explanation:

- `temp` CTE: Dedup data and introduce `dep` field - number of days since epoch to eliminate costly TIMESTAMP functions
- `round_trips` CTE: identify all round trip candidates with at most 4 days apart
- identify those LAX and LED round trips which have overlaps
- for each cityX take the cheapest combination
- final output does extra calculation on overlapping days in cityX and lean a little output to have info about all involve flights

Note: in your data - duration field are all zeros - so it is not involved - but if you would have it - it is easy to add it to logic

Comment: forgot to mention  - this took just 5-6 seconds

Comment: wow, this turned out to be way more complex than i initially expected... Thanks for the detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

> the query didn't finish in 30 minutes and I had to abort it.
> Is there a way to optimize this query for better performance?

My "generic recommendation" is to always learn the data, profile it, clean it - before actual coding! In your example - the data you shared has 469352 rows full of duplicates. After you remove duplicates - you got ONLY 14867 rows. So then I run your original query against that cleaned data and it took ONLY 97 sec to get result. Obviously, it does not mean we cannot optimize code itself - but at least this addresses your issue with "query didn't finish in 30 minutes and I had to abort it"

Comment: true, the data might be having duplicates, because some of the fields were omitted while writing to the DB. Thanks for the recommendation! However, 97 seconds is still an insanely long time for a query on 14k records, so I would like to see solutions other than brute force if anyone here has ideas

Comment: sure, as promised  - i still will look at real optimization and will get back here when done :o)